# Two hard drives, one win10 and other Linux, end result is sda and sdb Linux confusion

Tags: dual-boot

*How do I point the system to the correct sdb5 partition?*

To install I removed Window 10 hard drive to install Peppermint OS, because it did not recognize second hard disk where I wanted to install Linux, it only gave me the option to dual install on Windows 10 disk.

Once the main hard disk was removed, Linux recognized the second hard disk but using sda to install the OS. Which I understand, because there was not a second hard disk at the time.

After installing Linux, I reinstalled the Win10 hard disk on the main hard disk bay. Once I did that, Linux renamed its disk as sdb automatically. Now,the system runs without swap because it expects its swap partition to be on sda.

Running `swapon` does not correct the problem because it expects sda5, which is not correct. Note how `etc/fstab` displays that the original installation was on /dev/sda1 and also swap partition was made on /dev/sda5.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c9f3ceae-725a-4042-8571-8099361f264b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=efc2e006-9040-xxx-xxxxx-157e5e5ec0e5 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

When I run the command sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x93368b07

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048 476877420 475851373 226.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       487380992 488394751   1013760   495M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE


Disk /dev/sdb: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf9090822

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048 608497663 608495616 290.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       608499710 625141759  16642050     8G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       608499712 625141759  16642048     8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 8 GiB, 8520204288 bytes, 16641024 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

This is the output of /etc/cripttab

```
cryptswap1 UUID=efc2e006-9040-44f6-xxxx-157e5e5ec0e5 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

Should it read?

```
cryptswap1 /dev/sdb5 UUID=efc2e006-9040-44f6-xxxx-157e5e5ec0e5 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

No it should read:

```
cryptswap1 /dev/disk/by-uuid/efc2157....  /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

Edit3
The difference is impressive. I'm on a disk drive and after reboot my computer is noticeably faster and can handle many more documents and programs at once.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an encrypted swap. To fix your problem you should look for /etc/crypttab. It is similar to the `fstab` and contains a list of encrypted devices to be unlocked at boot.
At the beginning you should see something like `cryptswap1 /dev/sda5`.
So, change it to whatever your swap partition now points to.
Or you can set UUID there like `cryptswap1  UUID=efc2e006-9040-44f6-a14c-157e5e5ec0e5`. If you use /dev/sd* scheme, make sure you point it to a correct partition (according to your fdisk output, /dev/sdb5 is your swap partition now). This partition will be used as an encrypted swap after next system restart so make sure you set it correctly!
As mentioned by *dirkt*, you can see UUIDs in your system by executing `ls -al /dev/disk/by-uuid/`. `blkid` program can also show UUIDs.